# updating the user model directly in the req.user in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am taking a full stack react course from an online learning platform, in which I am using `node` and `express` as the server, `passport` for authentication and MongoDB as the backend database. So I have a flow where when the user logs in a cookie is attached to the user, so on subsequent request from the user, the cookie is deserialized and the user record from the DB is stored in the `req.user`.

So I have a billing system which uses the stripe, where when the amount is charged he can create surveys (say $1 for 1 credit). Now I have the user model in the mongo db as

```
 user: 
{ _id: abc,
  googleId: xyz,
  __v: 0,
  credits: 0 },
```

Once when the user pays the amount the credits has to be updated and it has to be reflected in the front end in the header.

```
const keys = require('../config/keys')
const stripe=require('stripe')(keys.stripeSecretKey);

app.post('/api/stripe',async (req,res) => {
const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 500,
  currency: "usd",
  source: req.body.id, // obtained with Stripe.js
  description: "$5 for 5 credits"
})

req.user.credits +=5;
const user = req.user.save(); 
});
};
```

My question is: 
How come changing the `req.user` and saving it updates the user model in the DB. As in the above code, I could not see any import for the `mongoose` user model?

I was expecting something like `import` the user model -> `get` the user id from `req.user` -> then use `findById()` -> to identify the user in MongoDB and then make the change in the credits.

Answer (score 3):

**You are storing whole User model instance to req.user**
if you read [this issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/127) in that owner clarify everything and also because you are working with mongoDB and mongoose, req.user.save() worked [see this it depend on DB or/and ORM](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/127#issuecomment-16197348)
you can also verify it by

```
console.log(req.user instanceof mongoose.Model); // true
```

make sure mongoose is imported before use

Answer (score 1):

`req.user` is an instance of User model that's why the data was updated. I suggest you to read [this part](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/#sessions) from passportjs docs to understand how the user model is restored to `req.user` in each http request.